# Basic Apex repeat visualforce not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am working with Visualforce and apex, and I get this error with the value in the apex-repeat tag even with the basic code in the documentation, anyone knows why this error occurs.

The error :  Formula expression is required for attribute value in apex:repeat in Classname

Apex code :

```
public String[] getStrings(){return new String[]{'ONE','TWO','THREE'};}
```

VF page code :

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="ApexClassName">
      <apex:repeat value="{!strings}" var="string" id="theRepeat">
           <apex:outputText value="{!string}" id="theValue"/>
           <br/>
      </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

**UPDATE WITH CORRECT CLOSING TAGS**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!strings}" var="string" id="theRepeat">
    <apex:outputText value="{!string}" id="theValue"/>
    <br/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: I'm guessing there's a typo in your original code.  This code should work.

Comment: Thank you for commenting but, this code is a copy paste from my project, I have reviewed it many times, I don't know why it is not working. Is there anything I do have to check for the permissions or something like that?

Comment: is this the only vf page code you have? I agree with sfdcfox here code is executable after fixing apex-repeat typo.

Comment: Agree with @Himanshu. I missed the `-` typo the first time. Actually copy-pasting your code works just fine after fixing the typo.

Comment: @ArbaniOumaima I have updated your question with UPDATE section, as already commented by others, your apex-repeat closing tag was incorrect. Code works fine

Comment: Actually my code was 100% correct, all I did is restart vs code and it worked just fine...weird!